# How can I publish to a Maven repository hosted on bitbucket using gradle?

Tags: java, git, maven, gradle, artifacts

The information for this I find on the web is 5 years old.

Basically I want to use the function of the plugin
https://github.com/synergian/wagon-git

However the Plugin no longer supports Bitbucket v2.

How can I publish an artifact to a Maven repository hosted on bitbucket using gradle?

Comment: hey, @flying-swissman did you have any luck figuring this out? I am trying to figure out the same thing myself.

Comment: @nassan no we are still looking for a solution

Comment: @flying-swissman I figured we would use the `maven-publish` plugin.  But I can't get passed a 403 error when trying to publish to the repo.  Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: So I've been working on the same thing to no avail as well. I actually rolled my Gradle back to 6.9 to allow for git-wagon to still work (it does not work with Gradle 7+). I think this issue is a bit more than just bitbucket, I believe it also has to do with how maven-publish works. I apologize if I'm a bit unclear as its been a few weeks since I was reading this document but it centers around PUT v POST in the publish plugin. I believe its that the publish plugin is trying to PUT to bitbucket and bitbucket 2.0 only supports POST or something along those lines.

Comment: @FlyingSwissman  Do you find any solution to achieve this ?

Comment: @RichardOry no, no luck

Comment: Been stuck at this for over 2 days now. Guess I'll just try GitHub Packages to see how it goes.